# Tomcat on ec2 works fine but after sometime it fails

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have deployed my java application on Tomcat running on aws.It works fine for initial hours but after that it fails while login.The login logic is a servlet called `AuthenticateUser`.Fails means it goes to the `AuthenticateUser` and it displays a blank page there.The thing is that I have opened many database connection but haven't closed any of them.Is it because of that?

Thanks.

Comment: "I have opened many database connection but haven't closed any of them." probably :) without your code we cannot tell ...

Comment: No doubt that inspecting the contents of the `logs` folder will be most illuminating.